# Deleting documents in mongo collection with _id attribute of a given BSON type

Tags: mongodb, removeall

I have a collection in which the `_id` of each document is of string type. Because of some problem, we inserted some documents with wrong _id of type `ObjectId`.

```
{
  "_id": "M123",
  "title": "Test",
  ...
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("566de977e4b075b86383b629"),
  "title": "Test",
  ...
}
```

Now I want to delete all the documents which are similar to the second one. Is there any way to specify this query to `db.Collection1.remove()`?

I tried searching on google, where i found queries which specifies conditions on a particular field values and not their types.

Comment: See [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

Comment: I tried the following query.  db.Collection1.find({"_id":{$type: "objectId"}}).count()
2016-03-17T16:26:25.271+0530 E QUERY    Error: count failed: {
 "code" : 10061,
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "exception: type not supported for appendMinElementForType"
}
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBQuery.count (src/mongo/shell/query.js:326:11)
    at (shell):1:44 at src/mongo/shell/query.js:326

Comment: The `"alias"` values are only supported in MongoDB 3.2. **All** versions use the numeric value. For example, to just find `_id` with BSON type of "string" `db.Album.find({ "_id": { "$type": 2 } })` which is of course BSON type `2` numerically.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven I am able to remove the documents using the query 'db.Collection1.remove({"_id":{$type: 7}})'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to delete the rows with _id of type ObjectId using the following query.

```
db.Collection1.remove({"_id":{$type: 7}})
```

This is for older version of the mongo before 3.0
For newer versions, you can also use

```
db.Collection1.remove({"_id":{$type: "objectId"}})
```